# Is there a way to get more pen pressure variance in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pen-tool

I have a Gaomon PD1560 screen, Photoshop CC, and the Lazy Nezumi plug in.

I have set my brush to have pen sensitivity turned on, and minimum width to zero in hopes of getting maximum variability. I want to be able to start at a thin line and work my way up to a thick link by pressing down on the brush. The amount of variance I want is represented in the image at the bottom brush settings dialogue:

[image]

But no matter how hard I try to recreate the varying thickness of that line, here's the best I can do:

[image]

The begining of the lines (on the left) start off immediately very round, close to 50% of the maximum thickness. I can get down to a sharper line only at the very end as I do a quick stroke and pull the pen away from the screen.

Supposedly this tablet has 8192 levels of pen pressure, but it feels like it has only 10% of that, and it's all at one end.

**Is this just a limitation of the tablet? Is there anything I can do to get my pen strokes to start thin and get thicker with pressure?**

Answer (score 1):

This really boils down to 2 things...

1) The tablet settings

and

2) Practice to learn how to create the light pressure effectively when needed.

Often more pressure levels can be *less* dynamic due to the difficulty in creating subtle differences in your hand/fingers.

There's nothing you can really do with Photoshop to adjust.

I have no experience with that tablet model and therefore can't offer any explicit setting suggestions. I do, however, know on my Wacom tablets I need to configure the tablet to be closer to "firm" settings rather than the default.